# Batch File to login and logout only once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing batch file that would execute 10 SQL scripts.

The SQL cmd code I used is

```
sqlcmd -S server  -U  username -P password  
        -d database_name -Q "select * from TrialBalance" -o "E:\Balance.txt"
```

Here I am have the server, user name and pass every time I use this command for the 10 sql scripts. is their any way my batch file could login into the SQL server using SQL authentication, run all the scripts and logout?

I think it will be more efficient right?

Comment: I doubt there's much overhead involved with 10 SQL authentication logins/logouts vs 1.  Not enough to be worth your time, IMO.  However, if it's really important, one option is to combine the 10 scripts into one (manually or programatically).

Comment: Are you looking for a way to do a simple data dump?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could look at the [:r](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1bc6fa86-8bb5-4cec-b17c-d0500b76944a/run-sql-files-using-r-command-unsing-mssql-management-studio?forum=sqlgetstarted) command.

here is a small example of what could work for you:

**Script A**

```
PRINT 'CREATING TABLES '
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('EMPLOYEE') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE DBO.EMPLOYEE
GO
CREATE TABLE DBO.EMPLOYEE
(
EMPLOYEEID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(50),
LASTNAME VARCHAR(50)
)
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('TIMECARD') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE DBO.TIMECARD
GO
CREATE TABLE DBO.TIMECARD
(
TIMECARDID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
EMPLOYEEID INT NOT NULL,
HOURSWORKED TINYINT NOT NULL,
HOURLYRATE MONEY NOT NULL,
DATEWORKED DATETIME NOT NULL
)
GO

DECLARE @TOTAL_TABLES INT
SET @TOTAL_TABLES = 2
```

**Scrip B**

```
PRINT 'TOTAL TABLES CREATED = ' + CAST(@TOTAL_TABLES AS VARCHAR)
GO
PRINT 'INSERTING DATA INTO EMPLOYEE'
GO

INSERT INTO DBO.EMPLOYEE (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) SELECT 'JOHN', 'DOE'
GO
INSERT INTO DBO.EMPLOYEE (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) SELECT 'JANE', 'DOE'
GO
INSERT INTO DBO.EMPLOYEE (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) SELECT 'JEFF', 'DOE'
GO
```

**wrapper script**

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO
PRINT 'Start...'
:On Error exit

:r D:\Temp\a.sql
:r D:\Temp\b.sql
PRINT 'Finish...'
```

A [link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1543/using-sqlcmd-to-execute-multiple-sql-server-scripts/) to the source of this example with a more in dept explanation

Answer (score 0):

If the commands are small you could also just include them in your SQLCmd separated by semicolons

```
sqlcmd -S server  -U  username -P password  
    -d database_name -Q "select * from TrialBalance; select * from GenLedger; select * from JournalEntry" -o "E:\Balance.txt"
```

You might also want to consider using Windows authentication so your credentials are not stored in your command and don't show up in your event logs.